# CROSSION usb 3 dock ethernet port

Tags: 16.04

I have this dock - (CROSSION Super Speed USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station) http://amzn.to/1UwZ3rO and I am trying to get the ethernet port working.

I believe it is using the Realtek RTL8153 chipset.  I am not 100% sure on this because I am just getting this information from the disk that accompanied the product.  It had a folder labeled RTL8153.

I have tried to find the manufacturers website and was unable to find it to look deeper for drivers.  The amazon page said this device had Linux support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out how to connect a moment after posting.

Basically you just need to figure out the device name being reported via this command

```
ifconfig
```

Mine was **enx002428fe52bc** so after that I just need to put the device into an "up" state.

```
sudo ip link set enx002428fe52bc up
```

You might have several devices listed so trying multiples didn't have any negative effects for me.